# max-height not resizing inner contents

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 5em;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
      This is a loooooooonnnng<br>text.<br> Spanning
      <br>multiple<br>lines.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Resize the browser window and you can see that the inner div is expanding more than the outer div in height. But, if I specify a height, say `height: 1000px;` on the outer div, the inner div gets resized to fit outer div's height. Why is it behaving like that? Isn't max-height supposed to work without specifying a height?

Comment: I am not sure if I got the question right ... testing your code with `#inner{height:1000px}` does not resize (= does not change the behavior of) the inner div. `#inner` still takes the height it needed as the inner content is long and don't grow up to a heigher outer div.

Comment: Thanks for notifying. I have missed a line in the CSS code (`height: 100%`). See my edit.

Comment: percentage height need height as reference and not max-height

Comment: for your particular case, remove height:100% and use display:flex on the outer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) property sets the maximum height of an element. It prevents the used value of the `height` property from becoming larger than the value specified for `max-height`.

When you use `max-height: 100%` on the parent container, the percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as `none`.

> In terms of `max-height`, if the content is larger than the maximum height, it will overflow.

To allow the child container to always fit inside the parent container, you can just use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) or add `overflow: auto` to `#outer` so then it does fit 100% of the content within it's content-box. Without using either `overflow` or Flexbox, the child container's content is larger than the maximum height and therefore overflows out the bottom of `#outer` when the viewport height is small.

Removing the `height: 100%` declaration from `#inner` while making the parent container a Flexbox with `display: flex` seems to do the trick without having to add `overflow: auto` to `#outer`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 5em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
      This is a loooooooonnnng<br>text.<br> Spanning
      <br>multiple<br>lines.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, `display: flex;` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Simply remove the `max-height` declaration from the `#outer` div.</s>

To fix your issue, supply a `height` property to your `#outer` div.

```css
#outer {
  /* ... */
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's not an option for me, since I don't want the outer div to grow more than its parent.

Comment: @Puspam, Please, check out my edit.